# Sorting a 2D array of integers by values in columns

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, columnsorting

I am trying to sort a `2D array` of integers in Java in increasing order according to the values of every column.

Let me explain my objective with the following example:

*This is my array*:

```
int[][] array = new int[][]{
        {7, 3, 9},
        {9, 1, 3},
        {5, 8, 8}};
```

*Here is the expected array*:

```
int[][] newArray = new int[][]{
        {5, 1, 3},
        {7, 3, 8},
        {9, 8, 9}};
```

As can see in the example, every values on `newArray` are the same as `array` but now ordered in each column in increasing order.

Almost all the questions in the forum are focused on how to sort a 2D array according to the values of a row or column, but I need this for every column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this.

- The static Lambda does the sort by column.  I did this to get around the effective final restriction on modifying local variables inside of streams, in this case the column.
- The `sortByColumn` method calls this lambda for each number of columns.
- This only supports rectangular matrices.

```
static BiFunction<int[][], Integer, int[][]> sortColumn = (arr,c) -> {
     int[] temp = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .map(i -> arr[i][c]).sorted().toArray();
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         arr[i][c] = temp[i];
     }
     return arr;
};
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array =
            new int[][] { { 7, 3, 9 }, { 9, 1, 3 }, { 5, 8, 8 } };
    
    array = sortByColumn(array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array)); 
}
```

Prints

```
[[5, 1, 3], [7, 3, 8], [9, 8, 9]]
```

```
    
public static int[][] sortByColumn(int[][] arr) {
     for (int col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++) {
         arr = sortColumn.apply(arr,col);
     }
     return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort the elements of the columns of a matrix, you can sort the elements of the rows of the transposed matrix and then transpose it back:

```java
int m = 3;
int n = 4;
int[][] arr = {
        {7, 3, 9, 2},
        {9, 1, 3, 1},
        {5, 8, 8, 7}};
```

```java
// sorting transposed matrix
int[][] arr2 = IntStream
        // iterate over the indices
        // of the rows of the matrix
        .range(0, n)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream
                // iterate over the
                // indices of the columns
                .range(0, m)
                .map(j -> arr[j][i])
                .sorted()
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// transposing sorted matrix
int[][] arr3 = IntStream
        // iterate over the indices of the
        // rows of the transposed matrix
        .range(0, m)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream
                // iterate over the
                // indices of the columns
                .range(0, n)
                .map(j -> arr2[j][i])
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr3).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[5, 1, 3, 1]
[7, 3, 8, 2]
[9, 8, 9, 7]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Sorting 2D array of integers by column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65576552/14940971)</sup>